# Reading multiple csv files into a Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am attempting to read multiple CSV files into a Pandas data frame. The CSVs aren't comma separated - the fields are delimited by a semicolon ";".

I based my code on the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe).

My data is all in a specific subdirectory: `/data/luftdaten/5331`

This is what I run:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

path =r'data/luftdaten/5331' # use your path

filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
count_files = 0
dfs = []
for filename in filenames:
    if count_files ==0:
        dfs.append(pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";")) 
        count_files += 1
    else:
        dfs.append(pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";", skiprows=[0]))
        count_files +=1

big_frame = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

I use `count_files` to monitor if it is the first CSV - in which case I import the headers. Otherwise, it skips the headers.

The code executes OK.

If I run it with a single file in that directory, everything is fine:

```
big_frame.info()
```

Output:

```
RangeIndex: 146 entries, 0 to 145
Data columns (**total 12 column**s):
sensor_id      146 non-null int64
sensor_type    146 non-null object
etc......
```

If I run it with 2 or more files in the directory things go wrong from the start.

Output with 4 files:

```
RangeIndex: 1893 entries, 0 to 1892
Data columns (total **33 columns**):
-2.077                 1164 non-null float64
-2.130                 145 non-null float64
2.40                   145 non-null float64
```

Running `big_frame.head()` on the single CSV version gives this, with the correct column names:

[image: output from importing single CSV]

While running the same with four files imported gives me this:

[image: output from importing 4 CSV files (cropped right)]

Is there anything obvious that I am doing which is causing not only the number of rows to grow but the columns too?

Your guidance would be gratefully appreciated!

Comment: No need to skip headers as concatenation will not append multiple headers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason why it's currently not working is when you do `skiprows=[0]` for each file after your first, that new dataframe has its second (index 1) row used as the column titles. Hence, when the frames are concatenated there are lots and lots of column headers that don't match. If you remove the `skiprows=[0]` it should work.

Assuming all of your files have the same header (or you're okay with `NaN` when they differ), you should be able to do this in a one-liner:

```
big_frame = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep=';') for f in glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")],
                      ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you @asongtoruin That worked perfectly and, besides solving the problem, is much more elegant than my code!